# Does \documentclass{book} by default take care of gutter for inner side of page?

Tags: margins, double-sided

I'm hoping to create a book at the site lulu using LaTeX instead of Microsoft Word, and they say:

> Leave at least .5" margins on all your pages. Most books will require a gutter of .2" to .3".

I know how to set the .5" margins, but I've never done much with the book documentclass. Do I need to specifically tell it to add a gutter? Whether or not gutter is added by default, I guess I need to know how to specify that .2", since that is pretty specific.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the `geometry` package to define the inner margin with the  `twoside` option. If you want to leave a 0.5" in each margin, plus a 0.2" for the binding:

`\usepackage[inner=0.7in,outer=0.5in]{geometry}`

EDIT:

After @egreg and @doncherry coment, the following configuration will be the preferred way:

`\usepackage[bindingoffset=0.2in, left=0.5in, right=0.5in]{geometry}`

Comment: Wouldn't `bindingoffset` be better? It works independently of `oneside` or `twoside`.

Comment: @egreg You are right. I miss this option.  In this case I guess that the configuration will be `\usepackage[bindingoffset=0.2in, left=0.5in, right=0.5in]{geometry}`

Comment: I got used to `hmargin={0.7in,0.5in}`, the package will assume `inner/outer` or `left/right` according to `oneside` or `twoside` option (non)present.

Comment: @zunbeltz: Why don't you go ahead and edit that into your answer as the "preferred way"?

Answer (score 4):

You may also want to take a look at KOMA-Script book class (`scrbook`).  KOMA has built-in support for "binding correction":

```
\documentclass[BCOR=.5in]{scrbook}
```

The nice thing here is that KOMA-Scripts layout engine (`typearea`) incorporates this directly into the calculation of the layout.

If you do not want to use `scrbook`, you may also use the `typearea` package together with your favorite `book` class:

```
\documentclass[BCOR=.5in]{book}
\usepackage[BCOR=.5in]{typearea}
```