# PDF's page layout and dimensions not good for printing

Tags: books, printing, dimensions, layout

So now that I have a 600+ page PDF (`book`) on my hands, I'd like to get a print out of it -- never thought I would. Turns out that the PDF's page formatting is not right for the print-on-demand service I plan on using (Lulu).

This question has been asked before, here in particular: [Does \documentclass{book} by default take care of gutter for inner side of page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/80520/does-documentclassbook-by-default-take-care-of-gutter-for-inner-side-of-page)

I've attempted to implement the solutions offered, but neither of them have worked. For instance, below is the clean original layout (see code below for its dimensions):

[image]

And here's the adversely impacted layout once I've applied the solutions mentioned [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/80523/90984) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/81616/90984).

[image]

Obviously, I'd rather not go over laying out the whole document again.
What options do I have, considering that, for hardbacks, Lulu requests the following dimensions:

Live Area (the page as it appears in the PDF): 190.5mm x 266.7mm
Trim Area: 212.7mm x 279.4mm
Document Size: 231.8mm x 317.5mm

Thank you.

See below for my PDF's dimensions:

```
\documentclass[oneside,centered,twocolumn]{book}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\special{papersize=190.5mm,266.7mm}
\usepackage[left=12.7mm,right=12.7mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Comment: Changing the paper size is easy. But your current \textwidth is 16.48cm, the requested size is 19.05cm. I don't see what you can do here apart redoing the layout or finding another publisher.

Comment: Well, that's a bummer. I thought the dimensions I was using were standard, and didn't check with Lulu. Yikes. I have no interest re-laying out the book as I've had my fill, but would my updated code (see above) work, if for some reason I thought redoing all my work was a good idea?

Comment: No need to redo all, change paper size and check nothing gets too messed up (floats -- like figures and tables -- wil probably move around, paragpraphs will change somewhat. Longer lines should be no problem (no equations suddenly split at random places, for example). Check any equations split by hand, the might now look funny (too short for the line), however.

Comment: Yes, it came to me after some more research and thought. I've now decided to go ahead and put together a hardback, print-on-demand version of the PDF. It's not that daunting, although it is a bit more work. (see the code in my answer for the ones interested)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the code I've come up with to give my document the layout Lulu requires for their POD hardbacks. As suggested, it's then "simply" a question of going through the entirety of the book, page by page, and check that all the elements that make up the document look fine.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{book}
%\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\linespread{1.05}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    paperwidth=212.7mm, paperheight=279.4mm,
    tmargin  =30mm,
    bmargin  =30mm,
    lmargin  =35mm,
    rmargin  =25mm,
    headsep  =0.5cm,
    footskip =0.5cm,
    columnsep=.3cm,
    headheight=.5cm
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```